# Building tensorflow-text=2.11.0 from source fails with "rev: command not found" on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

As you may know, after version 2.10, tensorflow-text is not be provided as a pip package on windows.

I tried to follow the Build from source procedure at https://github.com/tensorflow/text#build-from-source-steps, but it fails at step 3 :

```
sh ./oss_scripts/run_build.sh
```

I got:

```
...
+++ python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print('\'' '\''.join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))'
+++ awk '{print $2}'
+++ python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.CXX11_ABI_FLAG)'
++ TF_ABIFLAG=0
++ HEADER_DIR='C:\Users\Gilles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include'
++ SHARED_LIBRARY_DIR='C:\Users\Gilles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow'
+++ echo -l:libtensorflow_framework.so.2
+++ rev oss_scripts/configure.sh: line 88: rev: command not found
+++ cut -d: -f1
+++ rev oss_scripts/configure.sh: line 88: rev: command not found
++ SHARED_LIBRARY_NAME=
```

My config:

- Windows 10
- Python 10
- Tensorflow 2.11.0 (pip install)

Answer (score 0):

This build script which you have mentioned is used for **MacOS**.

`Tensorflow-text 2.11` pip package is only available for Linux or intel based MacOS, not for Windows. Please refer to this [document](https://github.com/tensorflow/text#a-note-about-different-operating-system-packages).

You can still install `Tensorflow-text 2.10` using pip which will downgrade Tensorflow to 2.10 for the [same version](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/tf_text_intro#install_using_pip) which is likely to support each other apis.

```
!pip install tensorflow-text==2.10
import tensorflow_text as tx
tx.__version__  # '2.10.1'

Import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__  # '2.10.0'
```